# Generate hashed name for SSH known_hosts

Tags: openssh, ssh-keygen

Is there an easy way to generate hashed hostnames to be added to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file?

I'd like to add a `@cert-authority` line to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Obviously the `ssh-keygen` command would not get the CA cert. 
I think it also needs a connection to the server,
and I'm not sure I can get it to hash a wildcard.

So, how would I hash `"*.bar.com"`, for example,
so that it can be used in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file?

**Edit**: Having thought about it, hashed wildcards probably can't work, as it would be too difficult for the client to match a wildcard after it has been hashed. But, if I can still get a method to hash a domain without requiring a connection to the server (as `ssh-keygen` does), that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the hostname for an *existing hashed host*, edit your `known_hosts` file, replacing the hashed hostname with the plaintext hostname you wish associated with that key, and rehash the file:

```
ssh-keygen -H
```

---

If you want to generate hashes for a list of hostnames without disturbing your `known_hosts`, create a file combining the hostnames you wish to hash with a valid key copied out of an existing `known_hosts` :

```
sample.bar.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2...
other.bar.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2...
diff.domain.org ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2...
```

Then hash this file using `ssh-keygen` :

```
ssh-keygen -f mytestfile -H
```